# Error - unknown identifier: "opens_count"

Tags: sendgrid

I am trying to get records with following filter: `status` -> delivered, query -> `last_event_time` between 2 datetime, `opens_count` more than 1, and custom `subject` message.

part of request:

```
Array
(
    [status] => delivered
    [query] => last_event_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2022-03-25T00:00:00.000Z' AND TIMESTAMP '2022-03-25T23:59:59.000Z' AND opens_count >= 1 AND subject LIKE "query string%"
    [limit] => 2
)
```

response:

```
Array
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [message] => unknown identifier: "opens_count"
                    [field] => query
                )

        )

)
```

I see `opens_count` is not in list of available [filters](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/e-mail-activity/filter-all-messages).

I am using [SendGrid-PHP](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) library. My code is working fine if I remove `opens_count` filter, but then it returns all records including `opens_count` with 0.

How can I get records opened more than 1 time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see `opens_count` is not in list of available filters.

You've very much diagnosed your own issue here. `opens_count` is not an available filter, so you can't filter by it in an API request.

In this case you are probably best served by dropping the `opens_count` filter from the API request and filtering out the messages that have an `opens_count` of 0 once you have fetched them all.